# ¿Puedo crear traits con propiedades propias del trait?

Tags: php, poo, php7

quisiera hacer lo siguiente: Teniendo 1 trait y una clase que usa ese trait, y dichos componentes son los siguientes:

**Trait Saludo**

```
trait Saludo
{
    protected  $mensaje= 'Hola mundo';
 
   protected function saludar()
{
    //
    return $this->$mensaje;
}

   

}
```

**Class Altavoz**

```
class Altavoz
{
    //traits
    use Saludo;
}
```

**Test**

```
$altavoz = new Altavoz();
$altavoz->saludar(); // Hola mundo
```

¿Hay alguna forma de poder hacer eso?. Es decir, que el **trait** contenga propiedades propias independientemente de que clase sea la que use ese trait ?

Answer (score 1):

Si nos referimos a la [doc. oficial de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php) en el apartado de *traits*, podemos leer que:

1. Los traits **SI** pueden definir propiedades
2. La clase que use el trait no debe definir una propiedad que tenga el mismo nombre que la que fue definida dentro del contexto del trait
   2.1. Exceptuando que su modificador de acceso sea el mismo así como el valor asignado

Para el punto número 2.1, lo podemos observar en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

trait algunosMetodos {
    public int $primerValor = 10;
    
    public function retornaValor() 
    {
        return $this->primerValor;
    }
}

class Ejemplo
{
    public int $primerValor = 10;
    use algunosMetodos;
}

$instanciaUno = new Ejemplo();
echo $instanciaUno->retornaValor();
```

Con una salida como esta:

> 10

Sin embargo para este mismo ejemplo, si declaramos dentro de la clase una propiedad con el mismo nombre, pero modificando su valor asignado así:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

trait algunosMetodos {
    public int $primerValor = 10;
    
    public function retornaValor ()
    {
        return $this->primerValor;
    }
}

class Ejemplo
{
    public int $primerValor = 101;
    use algunosMetodos;
}

$instanciaUno = new Ejemplo();
echo $instanciaUno->retornaValor();
```

Obtendremos un error fatal de este tipo:

> **Fatal error**:  Ejemplo and algunosMetodos define the same property ($primerValor) in the composition of Ejemplo. However, the definition differs and is considered incompatible. Class was composed in **[...][...]** on line **13**

*Ojo!* que este error fatal solo aparecerá si trabajas en alguna versión moderna de PHP, desde la 7 en adelante, dado todo lo anterior entonces si puedes pero atendiendo a las observaciones realizadas.

O también tienes la opción **dependiendo** como estés concibiendo el proyecto y sus necesidades entonces declarar un *trait* que contenga únicamente las propiedades deseadas y construir el método que las manipule dentro del cuerpo de la clase:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

trait algunosMetodos {
    public int $primerValor = 10;
    private string $segundoValor = 'cadena de algo';
}

class Ejemplo
{
    use algunosMetodos;
    
    public function muestraValores()
    {
        return "{$this->primerValor} y {$this->segundoValor}";
    }
}

$instanciaUno = new Ejemplo();
echo $instanciaUno->muestraValores();
```

Con una salida así:

> 10 y cadena de algo

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, estoy probando añadir atributos a la clase como mencionas aqui, pero me lo subraya en orjo (y me da error) y cuando hago uso de $this no me deja. Es decir, tengo esta propiedad : `public  $storagePathFiles = '/ficheros';` , no me da error en si la propiedad, pero luego  desde una funcion de esta no puedo acceder a ella mediante `$this`, por tanto no me sirve de nada tener una propiedad que no es accesible no? o que estoy haciendo mal ?. Un saludo y gracias de nuevo.

Comment: El error que me da cuando uso `$this` en una de sus funciones es : `Error: Using $this when not in object context` Por lo que he buscado es debido a que los traits son parecidas a las `abstracts class` por tanto no tiene sentido que existan por si solas, solo deben existir como resultado de una herencia sobre una clase, pero yo quiero que esta clase tenga ciertas propiedades mara aumentar la utilidad que necesito.

Comment: con cuál de los ejemplos te dió ese error? @josanangel

Comment: en cualquiera que ponga $this dentro de un trait. He hecho otra pregunta que desarrollo mi problema más a fondo.